# How can I correctly type this object converting?

Tags: typescript, types, type-safety

How can I achieve typesafety for this converting case? I'm mapping over the `palette` and convert any object with entries to key value pairs, like tailwindcss does for their color configuration. However the type of `colors` don't contain the gray colors instead only the non converted entry keys as type.

```
const palette = {
    white: 'white',
    gray: {
        100: '#eeeeee',
        200: '#e0e0e0',
        300: '#bbbbbb',
    },
};

type ColorVariants = keyof typeof palette;

function convertToColors(color: ColorVariants) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(palette[color]).map(([key, value]) => [`${color}${key}`, value]),
    );
}


/**
  result -> 
  {
    "gray100": "#eeeeee",
    "gray200": "#e0e0e0",
    "gray300": "#bbbbbb",
  }
 */
const grays = convertToColors("gray")
```

Types not correct here

```
// Resulting Type
// const colors: {
//    white: string;
// }
//
// Expecting Type
// const colors: {
//    white: string;
//    gray100: string;
//    gray200: string;
//    gray300: string;
// }
const colors = {
   white: palette.white,
   ...convertToColors("gray")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

Let's edit `convertToColors` to this:

```
function convertToColors<Color extends ColorVariants>(color: Color): Variants<Color, typeof palette[Color]> {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(palette[color]).map(([key, value]) => [`${color}${key}`, value]),
    ) as never; // cast to return type; "ignore" error
}
```

It takes a color, and gives us the variants object for that color.

This is the proposed `Variants` type:

```
type Variants<K extends string, T extends string | Record<string | number, string>> = T extends string ? T : {
    [V in keyof T as V extends string | number ? `${K}${V}` : never]: T[V];
};
```

First it checks if the given color doesn't have any variants (it's just a string, not an object).
Then it remaps all keys in the variants as the variant + its intensity.

You can see that it works beautifully well [here](https://tsplay.dev/mb0Y9w).

Answer (score 0):

you can use union in This case :

```
type ColorVariants = string | {[prop:number]:string};
```